# Stacking images vs slides

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm working an a little game that is online. It's a probability game and I'd like to have a few slides that have information and then the actual game. I'm using html & javascript to make the game and then css (which I don't know yet) to make it look better.

How would I go about creating different pages, should I just have an image and then make it opaque when I don't need it and then show another one over it?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm sure there is a much better way to do this but don't know how because I'm new to web coding.

Comment: what about using jquery plugin for image slide http://plugins.jquery.com/WOWSlider/

Comment: I don't know any JQuery and would be more comfortable using only HTML or JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: jquery is js at the end, but as you see in the plugin it does magic with little effort

Comment: But I'm not only looking to play images, I'll have only two images and then the actual game which involves buttons and such, and I'd like to switch between them. Kind of like states. Edit: I'm on Linux and that only had a windows installer.

Answer (score 1):

you can make two separated pages.

> contain the images one after another .. first image will have JS onclick .. on this function you will hide this image and show the other image
>
> second image will be treated like link to the game page.